# Check if QMainWindow is displayed before displaying popup PySide Qt

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I would like to display a QMessageBox to the user to open a file once my QMainWindow class has been displayed. I have called the QMessageBox as the last call in the **init** method of the main window, but the issue is that it is popping up before the QMainWindow class has had a chance to show.

I could set the QMessageBox code to delay with a timer, but this seems like a very bad way of achieving what I am after. is there a better way?

Comment: How about creating a socket to open QMessageBox and emit related signal after QMainWindow has been initialized?

Comment: if I were to emit a signal at the end of init to a slot (lets call it showQMessageBox) opening the messagebox, how is this different from just calling showQMethodBox directly at that same point?

Comment: I meant something similar to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15884396/2040487). Connecting display with `show` event of the QMW. If this doesn't help you always can run `QTimer` to emit delayed signal calling the QMB.

Comment: ah I see, that will work thanks. the reason I don't want to use QTimer is that obviously the window will take differing times to show depending on the system speed so would have unpredictable results